# PHP: - Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.php on line 32

Tags: php

I am trying this:

```
if( ! isset( $_SESSION['type'] ) and !$_SESSION['type'] == "0") 
{
    echo "something";
}
```

i will get the out put:

> Notice: Undefined index: type in x:\xxx\xxx\xxx.php on line 32

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to use `||` instead of `and`

Comment: That would mean "or". Moreover, php supports both notations: `&&` and `and`, `||` and `or`.

Comment: You probably want: `if(!isset($_SESSION['type']) && $_SESSION['type'] !== "0")`

Comment: Did any of the any of the answers below work.  If so you should select it as the answer so they get the reputation points.

Answer (score 3):

PHP will issue a warning (notice) if you try to read from an array key that does not exist. `isset()` will not issue a warning.

However, your code is guaranteed to do that if 'type' is not set because the second half of the `if` will run if the type key is not set.

It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps you mean something like:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['type']) || $_SESSION['type'] == '0') 
{
  echo "something";
}
```

But ideally you'd do something like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['type']))
{
  $_SESSION['type'] = '0'; // set default value
}
```

Now the rest of the code can assume it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement is saying it is not set.... remove the first not (!).

Try this:

```
if(  isset( $_SESSION['type'] ) && ( $_SESSION['type'] !== "0")) {

   echo "something";
}
```

Comment: @RonniSkansing... That would work too I was trying to give him something that was more familiar to what he originally had.

Comment: @RonniSkansing you are right... === checks type and value making it more thorough and absolute.  I will edit the answer I gave.

Comment: @RonniSkansing I upvoted your commit thank you for helping me give a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
( isset( $_SESSION['type'] ) == false || $_SESSION['type'] != "0") ? 'something' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is a good approach:

```
if(  isset( $_SESSION['type'] ) && ( !$_SESSION['type'] == "0")) {

   echo "something";
}
```

This is saying if the session variable type is set and not equal to zero, then echo.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: -1  == '0' does not check if it is to "0" / try null, 0. And is almost a cp of the already existing answers

Comment: what does cp mean?  This is my first time using this site.

Comment: sorry i meant it was a copy and paste